# Node JS on AWS instance - is there a network limit?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

So I have an instance (m4.large, if it matters) on AWS, and a node JS script that is crawling through 10K sites over the web (specific ones).

On my simple Macbook Pro, it takes ~3 minutes. However, on AWS it's much slower and most of the requests gets lost (timeout), especially after running over a few hundreds (I guess it's a bug with Node?).

Anyway, is there a network limitation on AWS? I can't get more than 14 concurrent connections.
Here's how I send those requests:

```
    var request = http.request({
        method: 'GET',
        host: websiteDomain,
        port: 80,
        agent: agent,
        path: '/'
    }, function(response){
        // some code...
    });
```

Comment: i mean... when your crawling like that, you really should have some kind of throttle so that you're not impacting the sites you're crawling. i suspect that will also fix any network throughput issues you're having.

Comment: No worries, @KevinB - each of the crawled websites gets up to 1 request per week :)

Comment: gotcha. So it's more of, you're hitting 10k different pages, not necessarily crawling each entire site.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://serverfault.com/questions/324883/aws-bandwidth-and-content-delivery/326797#326797 your server has "Moderate" network performance, so if that serverfault answer is accurate, you're "cap" is 10MB/s. Please note however that the numbers are old, and are likely different by now.

Comment: I wish those numbers were correct in my case. I get 14 concurrent connections (including mysql and other stuff) with approx. 100kb/s. That's exactly my problem and that's exactly why I asked the question. Thanks.